# How to handle the login handshake in SSL but everything else in plaintext?

Tags: linux, sockets, ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL.

I can call SSL_set_fd to attach the socket to my ssl instance.  But what needs to be done when I no longer wish to encrypt the data but do wish to continue to communicate on the socket?

The reason is to not incur the computational overhead of SSL on the less-sensitive data.  I just wish to protect the credentials.

**Edit**:  I will be adding a Message Authentication Code (MAC) to all unencrypted messages from the client to the server in order to prevent the connection from being hijacked and the user impersonated.

**Edit**:  .NET's SslStream class provides a handy boolean on the constructor that controls whether or not the underlying stream will be closed when the SslStream is closed.  I'm looking for something similar in the OpenSSL C++ library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an SSL/TLS session has been established for a connection, it cannot safely be reverted back to an unsecure state.  If you only want to encrypt a portion of a communication, then encrypt the data you need, not the entire connection.  For instance, several Internet protocols (email, HTTP, etc) use SASL mechanisms for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

SSL (the protocol) deliberately provides no way to do this.  If it did, after you dropped your session back out of secure mode, a network attacker would be able to take over the TCP connection and impersonate the authenticated user.  And that would defeat the purpose of encrypting the credentials in the first place.

Comment: No, because I was planning on using a MAC on all messages from the authenticated user.

Comment: The people who designed SSL didn't trust application-layer programmers to do that correctly.  There really isn't any way to do what you want.

Comment: If the cypher be changed without dropping the connection and the cypher can be asymmetric, then the one-way MACs could be implemented at the cypher level.  And perhaps such a "cypher" has already been created.  But I doubt all of those are true.

Comment: When talking about a web site, it's trivial to use HTTPS for the login and then switch to HTTP for everything else.  In that case, the application-layer programmer must use a MAC to prevent session hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any *point* in doing this, because the computational overhead of SSL is frontloaded in the initial session setup, where the asymmetric cryptography is used.  Once the session has been set up, only symmetrical algorithms are used, which have trivial overhead.

Comment: When you downvote, it's considered courteous to leave a comment explaining what you feel is unhelpful about the answer.